# Send files from Qt application on ethernet

Tags: qt, tcp, ethernet

I want to send files from Qt Application using Ethernet.As I click push Button the files must be transfered.
so my Question is:
Q: what are the configuration required because IP ,Net Mask is fixed in my device I am using :AM335x 
:Linux OS 
:Qt application

I am new to TCP/IP  tell me how to proceed;
from Ethernet I am able to download Qt application executable file from PC to  my device(AM335x)  and it is running well .
But I want to send files from Am335x device to other device or PC.

Regards
Praveen

Answer (score 4):

Basically what you want to be using is the Qt Network module. You can read about that here:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/qtnetwork-programming.html

And find a class list here:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/qtnetwork-module.html

Very briefly the two main classes you can use for TCP communication are QTcpServer and QTcpSocket. You can set up the server to listen for connections and it will return a QTcpSocket to do the actual communication. You can use the QTcpSocket for any outgoing communication.

If you don't want to use TCP, you can use datagrams (simpler, but ultimately less reliable). Here QUdpSocket is the main class to use, both for sending and receiving (you need to bind the socket to a port on your machine to receive).

It would be fairly easy to write a custom program to do simple file transfer based on these classes, however you can also look at higher level protocols designed to deal specifically with files.

For simple interaction with an FTP server at the other end of the connection you can use the QFtp class. An example of an FTP client application is [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-qftp.html). Writing an FTP server in Qt would be rather more complicated, however you can look here: https://code.google.com/p/qt-ftp-server/.

All of this of this of course assumes that the Ethernet connection has been set up properly and that your computer has a valid IP address. Bear in mind that Ethernet is a link layer protocol and forms the raw basis for the higher level IP and TCP protocols. The idea of the higher level protocols is that they can used over a variety of link layers throughout the internet. It would be very unusual to write a program that interacts directly with a link layer protocol (unless of course you are writing a network stack for an OS).

On most networks configuration of IP addresses/netmasks etc is handled by a DHCP server running on one of the devices, most commonly on the router connecting everthing (if you have DHCP already running, then you probably don't have to worry). Without DHCP you can usually configure a static address and netmask on most devices. Choosing them is a fairly simple procedure. [This page](http://faqintosh.com/risorse/en/guides/net/tcp/basic/) has a fairly good introduction to the concepts.

Answer (score 1):

At first, you must be sure, that the target you want to send file to, is reachable. Use **ping**. If **ping** call is successful, then you can go further. Otherwise you should check your [network settings](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialNetworking.html) to comply with your LAN.

You have then various ways to send files: [FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ftp), [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http), via [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat), using [CIFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) etc.